# Error of Lookup on object of indeterminate type .... on a already annotated type

Tags: f#

Why am I getting an error of "Lookup on object of indeterminate type based on information prior to this program point...."

I have already annotated with type information.

It is highlighting the code `r.Read()`.

```
let rec foldResult myFunc accumulator r:SqlDataReader =
    if r.Read() then
        foldResult myFunc (myFunc 123456 accumulator) r:SqlDataReader
    else
        accumulator
```

Answer (score 20):

Put it in parens

```
let rec foldResult myFunc accumulator (r:SqlDataReader) = ...
```

Else you're annotating the return type of the function rather than the final parameter type.

Comment: Very helpful.  I would vote you up but stackoverflow says I don't have enough "reputation" yet.